# ¿Cómo enviar variable de un producto para ser cargado a un form de consulta en Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una vista que contiene un @foreach de productos con una descripción y un botón "Consultar". Lo que quiero es pasar los datos de este producto a un formulario para poder consultarlo por correo.

Vista de la descripción del producto:

$producto = DB::table('productos')->where('estado', '=', 'activo')
                                               ->where('categoria', '=', 'auto')
                                               ->get();

```
                  @foreach($producto as $productos)
                <div class="img-box">
                    <img src="Http://neumaticosarce.loc/img/{!! $productos->foto !!}">
                </div>
                <div class="txt-box">
                    <h2>{!! $productos -> nombre !!}</h2><br />
                    <h3>{!! $productos -> subtitulo !!}</h3><br />
                    <span>{!! $productos -> descripcion !!}</span>
                    <br/><br /><br />
                   <form method="get" action="/productos.consulta/{!! $productos-> nombre !!}">
                    <input type="submit" class="consultar" value="Consultar">

                      </form>
                    <br />
                </div>
                 <div class="separador"> </div>
                 @endforeach
```

Este es el Formulario:

```
form method="get" action="/productos.consulta/{!! $productos-> id !!}"
```

Este es el controlador:

```
public function consulta($id)
 {
   $productos = \neumaticosarce\productos::find($id);
   return view('productos.consulta' compact($id));
}
```

Este es el Formulario para consultar el producto x Correo:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'mail.store','method'=>'POST']) !!}

    <input name="name" type="text" autofocus required class="txt" placeholder="Tu Nombre" maxlength="50" /><br />
    <input name="email" type="email" required class="txt" placeholder="Tu direcci&oacute;n de Correo" /><br />
    <input name="prod" type="text" class="txt" value="{!! $productos-> id !!}"> /* o el nombre del producto*/
    <textarea name="mensaje" class="txt" rows="6" placeholder="Tu Consulta"></textarea><br />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" style="float: left; border:0; border-color: none; border-radius: 5px;"></div>
    <input id="correo" type="submit" value="Enviar">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona? ¿qué mensaje de error aparece?

Comment: Hola Shaz, modificando estas líneas en el controlador:
$productos = \xxxxxxxxxx\productos::find($id);
      return view('productos.consulta', ['producto'=>$productos]);
En la vista del formulario de onsulta me da este error:

Undefined variable: productos 

Este es el imput donde quiero cargar el valor del producto:
 <input name="prod" type="text" class="txt" value="{!! $productos-> id !!}">

Comment: Por favor, si vas a agregar información, házlo editando la pregunta, no se ve en el comentario.

Comment: No entiendo lo que pretendes explicar en tu comentario.

Comment: Reformulo mi solicitud de ayuda:
Tengo una vista que contiene un @foreach de productos con una descripción y un botón "Consultar". Lo que quiero es pasar los datos de este producto a un formulario para poder consultarlo x correo.
Espero haber sido más claro esta vez. ;)

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código completo de dicha vista y el método del controlador que la utiliza.

Comment: @GastonSlaiman agregué tu comentario en la pregunta. Por favor, a futuro, considera agregar todo el contenido relevante para la pregunta en la misma, no en un comentario.

Comment: No veo el foreach en la vista que compartiste

Answer (score 2):

Si vas a consultar algo de la base de datos, deberías usar GET en vez de post:

```
<form method="get" action="/productos.consulta/{{ $producto->id }}">
```

En tu archivo de rutas entonces deberías tener algo así:

```
Route::get('/products.consulta/{id}', 'productController@consulta');
```

Y en el controlador, el método si podría mantenerse tal y como lo tienes, aunque podrías utilizar algo más "Laravel" que es [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) y hacer más limpio aún tu código y aprovechar otras bondades del framework.